# How to save vCard from QR code in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

The output of the QR Code in swift is a String and i need to save `QR Code` if the Code contains a `vCard` with `swift`.

I am getting an error that says it cannot cast CNContacts to CNMutableContacts

```
func foundCode(code: NSString) {

    // Check if the QR Code is a website, contact, text etc

    let types :NSTextCheckingType = [.Link , .PhoneNumber, .TransitInformation]


    let checkTextType =  try? NSDataDetector(types: types.rawValue )

    let matchs = checkTextType?.matchesInString(code as String, options: .ReportCompletion, range: NSMakeRange(0, (code as String).characters.count))

    for match in matchs! {
        if match.resultType == NSTextCheckingType.Link {
            UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(NSURL(string: code as String)!)
        }
        if match.resultType == NSTextCheckingType.PhoneNumber {

            let vcard: NSData = code.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!
            let contactStore = CNContactStore()


            do {

                let saveRequest = CNSaveRequest() // create saveRequests

                let contacts  = try? CNContactVCardSerialization.contactsWithData(vcard) // get contacts array from vCard

                print("\(contacts)")

                for person in contacts! {


                      saveRequest.addContact(person as! CNMutableContact, toContainerWithIdentifier: nil) // add contacts to saveRequest

                }

                try contactStore.executeSaveRequest(saveRequest) // save to contacts

            } catch  {

                print("Unable to show the new contact") // something went wrong

            }
        }
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to convert `immutable` object `mutable`, that's why you are getting this error. Change you `saveRequest.addContact` line like this

```
saveRequest.addContact(person.mutableCopy() as! CNMutableContact, toContainerWithIdentifier: nil)
```

Hope this will help you.