# How to convert CNContact to CNMutableContact?

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, ios-contacts

I need to get contact, change it, and store back.

`CNContactStore().unifiedContacts` gives me `CNContact` instance, but `CNSaveRequest().update` requires `CNMutableContact`.

How to convert CNContact to CNMutableContact?

Comment: [This thread](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38051598/6541007) can be some help.

Comment: Thanks, just get a result in XCode.

Comment: Good Q, bc they didn't say much on how the two are related..

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Just found a way:

```
let mutableContact = contact.mutableCopy() as! CNMutableContact
```

Comment: Are there situations where you'd use `as? CNMutableContact` instead?