# How to add event in Calendar when scanned by QR scanner in swift iOS

Tags: ios, swift, events, qr-code

Before posted I did search for this answer but didn't find what I need so would like to ask if you kindly can help me.

I have iOS Swift app that scans QR codes which is in my case calendar event then show it as alert popup.
What I need is to scan QR Code (calendar event) and when scanned prompt if Event will be added into calendar, also limit scanning to event QR Codes.

Code that worked was from https://medium.com/@gayatri.hedau/qr-code-scanner-with-avcapturesession-ios-swift-5007ee498b49, but there you can just confirm that you have seen scanned info.

QR code with event info is created on https://qrcode.tec-it.com/en/Calendar

I don't know so much but I think that bellow part of code should be adjusted as this part shows alert QR code.

```
   func receivedCode(qrcode: String) {
    print(qrcode)
    let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Do you want to add event into your calendar?", message: qrcode, preferredStyle: .alert)
    let action1 = UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .default) { (action:UIAlertAction) in
        self.dismiss(animated: true)
    }
    alertController.addAction(action1)
    self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

When scanned QR Code I get this

> BEGIN:VEVENT
>   SUMMARY:Student meeting July
>   DESCRIPTION:Attend student meeting
>   LOCATION:Meeting room 21
>   DTSTART:20190710T140000Z
>   END:VEVENT

Also when scanned with similar QR Code app scanners from AppStore it shows that is calendar event.

Comment: Hope somebody will answer, I have the problem

Comment: Im looking into this code https://www.andrewcbancroft.com/2016/06/02/creating-calendar-events-with-event-kit-and-swift/ which has similar UIAalert.
Still not sure how to put this together with above or maybe something with the NSString's stringWithFormat that QR Code is formated to iCal or similar.
Still not smart enough to make this :)

Comment: And this QR Code to contacts is what we need but for calendar
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38051598/how-to-save-vcard-from-qr-code-in-swift
SO if someone can look at this and suggest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found a solution by manipulating the string value returned by the QR code:

```
var aStr = codeString.replacingOccurrences(of: "BEGIN:VEVENT", with: "")
aStr = aStr.replacingOccurrences(of: "\n", with: "")
aStr = aStr.replacingOccurrences(of: "SUMMARY:", with: "")
aStr = aStr.replacingOccurrences(of: "LOCATION:", with: "_")
aStr = aStr.replacingOccurrences(of: "DTSTART:", with: "_")
aStr = aStr.replacingOccurrences(of: "DTEND:", with: "_")
aStr = aStr.replacingOccurrences(of: "END:VEVENT", with: "")
print("\nEVENT STRING: \(aStr)\n")

// Make an array of aStr items
let evArr = aStr.components(separatedBy: "_")
let startDateStr = "\(evArr[2])"
let endDateStr = "\(evArr[3])"

// Get dates from Strings
let df = DateFormatter()
df.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")
df.timeZone = TimeZone.autoupdatingCurrent
df.dateFormat = "yyyyMMdd'T'HHmmss"
let startDate = df.date(from: startDateStr)
let endDate = df.date(from: endDateStr)

// Store Event in Calendar
let eventStore = EKEventStore()
eventStore.requestAccess(to: EKEntityType.event) { (granted, error) in
    if granted && error == nil {
        print("ACCESS GRANTED \(granted)")
        print("ERROR: \(String(describing: error))")

        let event = EKEvent(eventStore: eventStore)
        event.title = "\(evArr[0])"
        event.startDate = startDate!
        event.endDate = endDate!
        event.notes = "EVENT: \(evArr[0])\nLOCATION: \(evArr[1])"
        // Save Event...
        event.calendar = eventStore.defaultCalendarForNewEvents
        do { try eventStore.save(event, span: .thisEvent)
        } catch let error as NSError { print("Failed to save Event: \(error)") }

        print("Event saved in your Calendar app")
// error
} else { print("Failed to save Event: \(error!.localizedDescription)") }
```

Please note that this code handles a QR code of type **vEvent**, created on https://www.qrcode-monkey.com/#event. 
But if you create an Event on https://www.qrstuff.com, such event will be a **vCalendar** event type, so you'll need the code below to save it to the iOS Calendar app:

```
var aStr = codeString.replacingOccurrences(of: "BEGIN:VCALENDAR", with: "")
aStr = aStr.replacingOccurrences(of: "VERSION:2.0", with: "")
aStr = aStr.replacingOccurrences(of: "BEGIN:VEVENT", with: "")
aStr = aStr.replacingOccurrences(of: "\n", with: "")
aStr = aStr.replacingOccurrences(of: "\r", with: "")
aStr = aStr.replacingOccurrences(of: "SUMMARY;CHARSET=utf-8:", with: "")
aStr = aStr.replacingOccurrences(of: "LOCATION;CHARSET=utf-8:", with: "_")
aStr = aStr.replacingOccurrences(of: "DTSTART:", with: "_")
aStr = aStr.replacingOccurrences(of: "DTEND:", with: "_")
aStr = aStr.replacingOccurrences(of: "END:VEVENT", with: "")
aStr = aStr.replacingOccurrences(of: "END:VCALENDAR", with: "")

// Make an array of aStr items
let evArr = aStr.components(separatedBy: "_")
let startDateStr = "\(evArr[2])"
let endDateStr = "\(evArr[3])"

// Get dates from Strings
let df = DateFormatter()
df.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")
df.timeZone = TimeZone.autoupdatingCurrent
df.dateFormat = "yyyyMMdd'T'HHmmssZ"
let startDate = df.date(from: startDateStr)
let endDate = df.date(from: endDateStr)

// Store Event in Calendar
let eventStore = EKEventStore()
eventStore.requestAccess(to: EKEntityType.event) { (granted, error) in
    if granted && error == nil {
         print("ACCESS GRANTED \(granted)")
         print("ERROR: \(String(describing: error))")

         let event = EKEvent(eventStore: eventStore)
         event.title = "\(evArr[0])"
         event.startDate = startDate!
         event.endDate = endDate!
         event.notes = "EVENT: \(evArr[0])\nLOCATION: \(evArr[1])"

         // Save Event...
         event.calendar = eventStore.defaultCalendarForNewEvents
         do { try eventStore.save(event, span: .thisEvent)
         } catch let error as NSError { print("Failed to save Event: \(error)") }
         print("This Event has been saved in your Calendar app")

// error
} else { print("Failed to save Event: \(error!.localizedDescription)") }
```

Comment: I have used your first code, imported EKEvent, also changed 'var aStr = codeString ' to 'var aStr = qrcode' because that is my string as you can see in question , but after scan nothing happen, please can you advise if you used code inside function 'func receivedCode(qrcode: String)'?

Comment: yes, my code is inside s button, and the codeString variable is the value got after scanning the QR code

Comment: Thanks,  my version is automatic scan. Will check it that way.